# Unknown cause for Segfault in Gaussian Equation in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am currently making a program that approximates the Schroedinger equation, and for my initial conditions, my professor said to begin with a gaussian. The formula I'm using for that is this (apologies, I don't know how to do equations in markdown):

p(x) = ( 1/sqrt(2 * PI) ) * e^( -1/2 * (x-u)^2 / o )

I am starting with u=0 and o=1 for simplicities sake, and so the way I use it in my program is like this:

```
double gaussian(double x) {
    return (1/sqrt(2*M_PI)) * exp((-.5) * pow(x, 2));
}

void initial_conditions(int m, complex *values[], double dx) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        values[i]->real = gaussian(i * dx);
    }
}
```

Compiled by: gcc project1.c -lm -o project1

But that produces a segfault every time I have run it. As far as I can tell, it should work, but I am somewhat of a novice to C. I have determined it is specifically that equation that is producing the error by using printf statements to narrow the place of error down, and it always gets to that specific whole formula and return statement and then dies.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*I have no idea how to debug further*". Run the program in a debugger. It will instantly give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. And will also allow you to step thru the code and trace it as it runs. More debugging tips: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: After you have done your debugging and if you still need help please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: You're **sure** it's not dying trying to dereference `values[i]->` ?? Store the result of `gaussian` in a temporary double one line above, (eg. `double tmp = gaussian(...);` , then put a breakpoint on `values[i]->real = tmp;`. I'm betting the function isn't what is puking; it's the store after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`complex *values[]` is weird and unnatural. I can't see the invocation, but I have managed to convince myself that this really should be `complex values[]`.

A `complex` is far too simple a thing to want to allocate each one individually on the heap; almost always an array of `complex` would be allocated in a single call to `malloc()` (or possibly even a stack allocated array by caller).

Proceeding on from the names, I can project with decent confidence the calling code didn't allocate each individual `complex` in `values` but just allocated `values`, and thus the crash is the `->` dereference at `values[i]->real` and `values[i]` is uninitialized. It's like you want (carrying forward the single array) `values[i].real = ... ; values[i].imag = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was under the impression that complex *values[] would accept a pointer of an array of complex values, and also that the . and -> were essentially the same. Am I to understand that the -> is only used for specifically initialized variables, while the . simply carries out the action of going to where the value should be, and putting it there?

Comment: @ethanmorton No, `.` and `->` are not "essentially the same".  One's for grabbing members from a struct.  One's for grabbing members from a *pointer to* a struct.  So given `struct complex c` and `struct complex *cp = &c`, `c.real` and `cp->real` are equivalent.  In general, `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`.  And (in C, at least) one thing to keep pretty prominently in mind is whether you're working with a thing, or a pointer to a thing.  This is not something you can be sloppy about, and expect the compiler to glean your intent and clean up after you.

Comment: @ethanmorton: `->` is member access of `(complex *)` while `.` is member access of `struct complex`; thus `values[i]->real` is two layers of indirection while `values[i].real` is only one.

Comment: OK, I see now. Thank you for the information and help.